# What's is the difference between (someVar) => and (someVar) => {...} in react.js

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

What is the difference between this two functions in React.js?

`{muscles.map(group => { <Tab label={group} /> })}`

And

`{muscles.map(group => <Tab label={group} /> )}`

2nd line works properly but first line does not render values.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Did not know about that syntax

Answer (score 3):

The first line is a "multiline" arrow function. The code on the right side of `=>` is a block. As such, if your want to return a value, you have to return it explicitly:

```
{muscles.map(group => {
   return <Tab label={group} />;
})}
```

The second is an abbreviated syntax when the expression on the right side of `=>` is the return value of the function.

Comment: Great, thanks! Didn't know about that abbreviated  syntax

Comment: I think calling it "multiline" might add to confusion. It's not about the number of lines, it's about the fact that `{}` is a block

Comment: @loganfsmyth good point. In essence this is just JS design decision. In other languages (e.g. Groovy) this would work too because a function always returns the result of last statement.